# plotting multiple time series with different scales

Tags: python, matplotlib, time-series

I'm trying to plot 4 different dataframes over time to highlight possible relations between them.

I've met several difficulties:

1. different scales
2. same values overlap each other (IORR and IOER curves)
3. curves have big "points" making them unreadable
4. can't shift bar plots x values with df.index + 0.1 as I get an error

regarding the point 2, trying to shift the bars between the df IORR and IOER this way:

```
p1 = ax1.bar(df_ioer.index + 0.1, df_ioer.Value, ls='dashed', label='IOER', color='g')
ax1.xaxis_date()
```

I get this error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'float'
```

overall it's getting a little too much.
Could someone give a few pointers around this issue to get an intuitive representation of the data?

here is the code:

```
import quandl
from cycler import cycler
import matplotlib
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt


quandl.ApiConfig.api_key = "Get Free Key From Quandl.com"

df_dff = quandl.get("FRED/DFF")
df_iorr = quandl.get("FRED/IORR")
df_ioer = quandl.get("FRED/IOER")
df_gdp = quandl.get("FRED/GDP")

df_dff = df_dff[df_dff.index >= df_iorr.index.min()]
df_iorr = df_iorr[df_iorr.index >= df_iorr.index.min()]
df_ioer = df_ioer[df_ioer.index >= df_iorr.index.min()]
df_gdp = df_gdp[df_gdp.index >= df_iorr.index.min()]

# https://matplotlib.org/gallery/ticks_and_spines/multiple_yaxis_with_spines.html



plt.rc('axes', prop_cycle=(cycler('color', ['r', 'c', 'm', 'y', 'k', 'b', 'g', 'r', 'c', 'm'])))

def make_patch_spines_invisible(ax):
    ax.set_frame_on(True)
    ax.patch.set_visible(False)
    for sp in ax.spines.values():
        sp.set_visible(False)


fig, ax0 = plt.subplots()

#p0, = ax0.plot_date(df_iorr.index, df_iorr.Value, ls='dashed', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False, label='IORR', color='r')
#ax0.yaxis.label.set_color(p0.get_color())
p0 = ax0.bar(df_iorr.index, df_iorr.Value, ls='dashed', label='IORR', color='r')
ax0.xaxis_date( tz=None)


ax1 = ax0.twinx()
#p1, = ax0.plot_date(df_ioer.index, df_ioer.Value, ls='dashed', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False, label='IOER', color='g')
#ax1.yaxis.label.set_color(p1.get_color())
p1 = ax1.bar(df_ioer.index, df_ioer.Value, ls='dashed', label='IOER', color='g')
ax1.xaxis_date( tz=None)


ax2 = ax0.twinx()
p2, = ax0.plot_date(df_dff.index, df_dff.Value, ls='solid', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False, label='DFF', color='b')
ax2.spines["right"].set_position(("axes", 1.2))
make_patch_spines_invisible(ax2)
ax2.spines["right"].set_visible(True)

ax3 = ax0.twinx()
p3, = ax3.plot_date(df_gdp.index, df_gdp.Value, ls='solid', tz=None, xdate=True, ydate=False, label='GDP', color='y')

lines = [p0, p1, p2, p3]
ax0.legend(lines, [l.get_label() for l in lines])
plt.show()
```

result looks like this and is nowhere good enough.[image: multiple time series with various scales]

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't edit the code (easily) due to data dependency. However you may want to move the twiny data to log scale. The markersize can also be edited. What error are you getting?

Comment: sorry about the data dependancy, not sure how to avoid it.. regarding the error of the shift of the bars, using this code: p1 = ax1.bar(df_ioer.index + 0.1, df_ioer.Value, ls='dashed', label='IOER', color='g')
 I get this error: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'DatetimeIndex' and 'float' .

Comment: That makes sense as your x labels are actually objects. You can try and access the methods if the [DatetimeIndex](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.html), specifically year as that is the resolution here.